# DeleteTree fails on Hidden ReadOnly files

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild

In my msbuild script I have to clean a directory, which has some hidden readonly subdirectories. I was using the DeleteTree task, but it fails on these. What is the best way to delete a directory recursively regardless of file attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up simply executing rmdir with appropriate parameters. I still don't understand why it is good practice to use msbuild, it just makes life more difficult.